# Plotly Dash - Output a Specific Number of Checkboxes from Slider Input

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to output a specific number of checkboxes in Plotly Dash based on input from a slider. The aim is that a user will select a certain variable from a dropdown box and a value from a slider, which will then return a specific number of checkboxes (based on the slider) showing the variable's values.

At the moment the code works fine for one checkbox but I can't seem to find a way to loop through list of components in a div, and when I output more than one checkbox I receive a Callback error stating the expected length was 1 and received a greater value instead.

My current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import dash  # (version 2.0.0) pip install dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'CharName': ['VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1', 'VAR1',
                                'VAR2', 'VAR2', 'VAR3', 'VAR3'], 'CharValues': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'N',
                                                                                'Y', 'N', 'Y']})
chars_list = [{'label': char, 'value': char} for char in df['CharName'].unique()]

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# APP LAYOUT

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    html.H1(
        children='PLOTLY DASH',
        style={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'color': colors['text']
        }
    ),

    dcc.Dropdown(id="select_char",
                 options=chars_list,
                 multi=False,
                 value=df['CharName'].unique()[0],
                 style={'width': "40%"}
                 ),
    html.Br(),

    dcc.Slider(
        id='bin_no',
        min=1,
        max=7,
        step=1,
        value=3,
        marks={n: str(n) for n in range(1, 8)}
    ),

    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id="bins", children=[]),

])


@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='bins', component_property='children')],
    [Input(component_id='bin_no', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='select_char', component_property='value')]
)
def set_checkboxes(bin_no, select_char):
    dff = df.copy()
    dff = dff[dff["CharName"] == select_char]

    value_list = [{'label': value, 'value': value} for value in dff["CharValues"].dropna()]

    checklist_list = []
    for i in range(bin_no):
        checklist_list.append(
            dcc.Checklist(
                id=f'bin_{i}',
                options=value_list
            )
        )
    # return checklist_list

    return dcc.Checklist(
            id='bin_one',
            options=value_list
        ),


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thank you in advance!

Solution:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='bins', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='bin_no', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='select_char', component_property='value')],
    State('bins', 'children')
)
def set_checkboxes(bin_no, select_char, children):
    dff = df.copy()
    dff = dff[dff["CharName"] == select_char]

    # Null dropped for now due to error with no label or value
    value_list = [{'label': value, 'value': value} for value in dff["CharValues"].dropna()]
    checklist = []

    for i in range(bin_no):
        checklist.append(
            dcc.Checklist(
                id={'index': i},
                options=value_list
            )
        )
    return checklist
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error you have mentioned. And you can use pattern matching callbacks for this use case.

Comment: @snehilvj - Hi, I commented out the 'return checklist_list' statement  at the bottom, but if you uncomment this out and comment out the return statement below, the error message will appear. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To render the checkboxes properly, you need to return the checkboxes as children of the "bins" component. To make it clear to dash, change your callback signature to this:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='bins', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='bin_no', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='select_char', component_property='value')]
)
```

(Removed the square braces from the Output)

And you can use pattern matching callback for iterating over your dynamic checkboxes. [Link](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks)

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to get it working! The only issue now is that as I change the slider value the number of checkboxes grows e.g., if I change the slider to 4 then there are 7 checkboxes shown (3 is the default value). Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: hey, I don't seem to be facing this issue on my end. I see 4 rows of checkboxes, if I select 4 on the slider and 6 rows if I select 6 on the slider. https://imgur.com/a/nMNpdFg

Comment: managed to get it working now thanks :) I've added the solution above in my post. Would you know if this is the most effective solution to the problem?

Comment: can't say without knowing the complete picture